# Using Netbeans to push changes for Gerrit review

Tags: git, netbeans, push, gerrit

I have searched, but found little info on this. I've setup my own Gerrit server to host my personal projects. Using Netbeans plus the Git plugin, I can make changes and push back to the original branch, but I cannot find/figure out how to push for review (such as: git push HEAD:for/refs/master) so that Gerrit can be triggered for a review. I know how to do this from the command line, but need help from within Netbeans. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans doesn't currently support any Gerrit hooks for publishing commits.  I've been been creating my work branches in NetBeans, and then using GitExtensions for the initial commit and publish to Gerrit.  Patch commits work fine from NetBeans after that using the Amend Commit checkbox in NetBeans, but then you still have to publish to Gerrit.  If you know the command line to use though, this would be easy from the IDE using a terminal session.  I use Cygwin locally, but I think the sh shell that comes stock with NB would be fine for running any Gerrit publish commands you need.  Not as slick as having full IDE support, but a decent start.

EDIT: this is still the case, but please see my response to [Git pushing from Netbeans to Gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992512/git-pushing-from-netbeans-to-gerrit).  I hope it's helpful in this regard.